# Expecting dynamic types from a server response promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Resolved Promise object expecting a server response can either be an `any[]` or `{ data: any[] }` type.

I've tried this so far:

```
type ServerResponse = any[] | { data: any[] }
```

However, when I try to use the type, I get error messages such as these:

```
Property 'data' does not exist on type 'ServerResponse'. 
  Property 'data' does not exist on type 'any[]'. ts(2339)
```

or,

```
Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'ServerResponse'.
  Property 'filter' does not exist on type '{ data: any[]; }'.ts(2339)
```

Comment: This doesn't quite constitute a [mcve] as described in [ask].  Can you provide a standalone example of what you mean by "use the type"?  The answer is likely to be as simple as `Array.isArray(x) ? x : x.data` but without an actual example I can't be sure.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a Type Guard.  In the code below, the function `isAnyArray` is a type guard.

```
type ServerResponse = any[] | { data: any[] };

function isAnyArray(response: ServerResponse): response is any[] {
  return Array.isArray(response);
}

const someFunction(response: ServerResponse){
  if(isAnyArray(response)){
    response.forEach(x => {
      console.log(x);
    });
  } else {
    response.data.forEach(x => {
      console.log(x);
    });
  }
}
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types

Answer (score 1):

```
//this function will provide the response in array format
 function ServerResponse(res) {
        if (!Array.isArray(res)) {
        res = res.data;
        }
        return res;
    }

// initialize two types of response    
    const a = [];
    const b = {data:[]};

  // both response will be in Array format
    console.log(ServerResponse(a));
    console.log(ServerResponse(b));
```